# Boolean set to true in the Constructor

Tags: java, constructor, boolean, setter

For my first constructor, I used the parameters given to initialise the instance variables and for my second constructor I need to set all my booleans to true and this is what I have so far.

How do I fix the constructors below? Because I know there’s something wrong with it.

Thank you :)

public class Try {

```
private boolean a;
private boolean b;
private boolean c;
private boolean d;


public Try (boolean a, boolean b boolean c, boolean d) {      
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
    this.c=c;
    this.d=d;
}


public Try() {
    boolean a = true;
    boolean b = true;
    boolean c = true;
    boolean d = true;

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the constructors?

Comment: for the second constructor I don't know if i actually set the boolean to true, because it's not passing the test class I was given for a class project, and I don't know what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

For your default constructor, I assume you are trying to set the class attributes and not the local variables you have declared within the constructor. If so, you probably want something like this:

```
public class Try {

    private boolean a;
    private boolean b;
    private boolean c;
    private boolean d;

    public Try (boolean a, boolean b boolean c, boolean d) {      
       this.a=a;
       this.b=b;
       this.c=c;
       this.d=d;
    }

   public Try() {
        this(true, true, true, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not call the Boolean variable again in the constructor. It is already been initialized. Try the following edit in your code:

```
public Try() {
this.a = true;
this.b = true;
this.c = true;
this.d = true;
}
```

Happy Coding....

Answer (score 0):

**I can see both the constructors have some issue which are explained below:**

First, A **comma** , missing here near **boolean b** in the first constructor which will cause errors(**4 errors**) to be thrown at compile time. Replacing it with the below code will solve these errors:

```
public Try (boolean a, boolean b, boolean c, boolean d) {      
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
    this.c=c;
    this.d=d;
}
```

Second, when you will look carefully to the second constructor, you will feel it is just **initializing some local variables which is not going to be used anywhere in the program, so this is just writing some extra lines of code which will be not going to create any effect during object creation and initialization process**.

Writing the same code in below ways will be a good way to initialize the property of an object or just make it empty will also be a good way if you don't want to initialize properties when an object is getting created:

```
 public Try() {
        this(true, true, true, true);
 }
```

**or**

```
public Try() {
a = true;
b = true;
c = true;
d = true;
}
```

**or**  if initialization required as false

```
public Try() {}
```